# Typeset glyph boxes from The TeXbook, chapter 11

Tags: xetex, vertical-alignment, boxes

I've tried an example from The TeXbook but I do not get what Knuth says:
see the snippet below.
I should have got some rectangles but instead I've got the aligned text
which has letters exactly as typed in the source code.
What I'm doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: That's just an example. Later on he proposes this as an exercise (and provides his answer at the end).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is taken from the [TeXbook code](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/tex/texbook.tex) and transformed into a minimal example. To avoid influencing other list-like environments, I've placed it inside a limited-scope group (`\begingroup`...`\endgroup`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begingroup

\def\dolist{\afterassignment\dodolist\let\next= }
\def\dodolist{\ifx\next\endlist \let\next\relax
  \else \\\let\next\dolist \fi
  \next}
\def\endlist{\endlist}
\def\hidehrule#1#2{\kern-#1%
  \hrule height#1 depth#2 \kern-#2 }
\def\hidevrule#1#2{\kern-#1{\dimen0=#1
    \advance\dimen0 by#2\vrule width\dimen0}\kern-#2 }
\def\makeblankbox#1#2{\hbox{\lower\dp0\vbox{\hidehrule{#1}{#2}%
    \kern-#1 % overlap the rules at the corners
    \hbox to \wd0{\hidevrule{#1}{#2}%
      \raise\ht0\vbox to #1{}% set the vrule height
      \lower\dp0\vtop to #1{}% set the vrule depth
      \hfil\hidevrule{#2}{#1}}%
    \kern-#1\hidehrule{#2}{#1}}}}
\def\maketypebox{\makeblankbox{0pt}{1pt}}
\def\makelightbox{\makeblankbox{.2pt}{.2pt}}
\def\\{\if\space\next\ % assume that \next is unexpandable
 \else \setbox0=\hbox{\next}\maketypebox\fi}
\def\demobox#1{\setbox0=\hbox{\dolist#1\endlist}%
  \leavevmode\copy0\kern-\wd0\makelightbox}

Q: Construct a \verb|\demobox| macro for use in writing manuals
like this, so that an author can write `\verb|\demobox{Tough exercise.}|'
in order to typeset `\thinspace\demobox{Tough exercise.}\thinspace'.

A: The following solution is based on a general \verb|\makeblankbox|
macro that prints the edges of a box using rules of given thickness
outside and inside that box; the box dimensions are those of\/ \verb|\box0|.

\endgroup

\begin{verbatim}
\def\dolist{\afterassignment\dodolist\let\next= }
\def\dodolist{\ifx\next\endlist \let\next\relax
  \else \\\let\next\dolist \fi
  \next}
\def\endlist{\endlist}
\def\hidehrule#1#2{\kern-#1%
  \hrule height#1 depth#2 \kern-#2 }
\def\hidevrule#1#2{\kern-#1{\dimen0=#1
    \advance\dimen0 by#2\vrule width\dimen0}\kern-#2 }
\def\makeblankbox#1#2{\hbox{\lower\dp0\vbox{\hidehrule{#1}{#2}%
    \kern-#1 % overlap the rules at the corners
    \hbox to \wd0{\hidevrule{#1}{#2}%
      \raise\ht0\vbox to #1{}% set the vrule height
      \lower\dp0\vtop to #1{}% set the vrule depth
      \hfil\hidevrule{#2}{#1}}%
    \kern-#1\hidehrule{#2}{#1}}}}
\def\maketypebox{\makeblankbox{0pt}{1pt}}
\def\makelightbox{\makeblankbox{.2pt}{.2pt}}
\def\\{\if\space\next\ % assume that \next is unexpandable
 \else \setbox0=\hbox{\next}\maketypebox\fi}
\def\demobox#1{\setbox0=\hbox{\dolist#1\endlist}%
  \leavevmode\copy0\kern-\wd0\makelightbox}
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

You could write a similar `\demoletter{<letter>}` macro to put its contents into a box without printing it:

[image]

```
\newcommand{\demoletter}[1]{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}\fbox{\phantom{#1}}}}

\demoletter{O}\demoletter{n}\demoletter{e}
\demoletter{l}\demoletter{i}\demoletter{n}\demoletter{e}\demoletter{.}
```

Answer (score 6):

The code for that specific part of *The TeXbook* reads:

> ```
> For example, you can say
> \begintt
> \vbox{\hbox{Two lines}\hbox{of type.}}
> \endtt
> and \TeX\ will convert this into
> \begindisplay%
>   \setbox0=\vbox{\hbox{\demobox{Two lines}}\hbox{\demobox{of type.}}}
> $\vcenter{\hbox{\makelightbox\kern-\wd0\box0}}$\qquad
>   i.e.,\qquad$\vcenter{\vbox{\hbox{Two lines}\hbox{of type.}}}$
> \enddisplay
> ```

so you can see Knuth told you to type:

```
\vbox{\hbox{Two lines}\hbox{of type.}}
```

but he actually typed:

```
\vbox{\hbox{\demobox{Two lines}}\hbox{\demobox{of type.}}}
```

In Exercise 11.5, Knuth proposes you to build yourself the `\demobox` macro (which I will not show here, of course :-). After you do, you can use it like this:

```
\vbox{%
  \hbox{\demobox{Go try to solve}}%
  \hbox{\demobox{Exercise 11.5}}%
  \hbox{\demobox{by yourself :-)}}%
}
```

> [image]

Comment: Still, it would be useful if you copied the macro `\demobox` here, after all. I've tried to copy it and also correct it from Knuth's exercise, but it gives an error:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)
entering extended mode
 
 
! Parameters must be numbered consecutively.
<to be read again> 
                   l
l.74 \def\hidehrule#l
                     #2{\kern-#1%
? 

! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   l
l.74 \def\hidehrule#l
                     #2{\kern-#1%
No pages of o. **Perhaps I'm not running TeX but XeTeX?**

Comment: @user2925716 No, the error is because you probably copied from the PDF. You have `\def\hidehrule#l #2` (with an L and a space), whereas it should be `\def\hidehrule#1#2`. Copy from the TeXbook source instead. I didn't show the code because the idea is for you to learn to write the code, not copy it. The code works with either engine.